# How to merge Task Warrior database with FTP?

Tags: tasks, to-do

After loosing all my Task Warrior database, I'm trying to configure the synchronization feature of Task Warrior, but I'm running into some issues.

My server is not one of my computer, it's a web server. I just want to use it as a backup.

Here is my config :

```
merge.autopush=yes
merge.default.uri=ftp://user@mysite.com/taskwarrior/
push.default.uri=ftp://user@mysite.com/taskwarrior/
pull.default.uri=ftp://user@mysite.com/taskwarrior/
```

The problem is that the push commands push only the pending.data, not the completed.data neither undo.data.

Is that normal ?

I want to put all of them so that in the future I can use a second computer syncing with the same server without problem.

Is there a solution to my problem or task sync is not the good way to do that ?

Comment: Which version of Taskwarrior do you use?

Comment: I have the 1.9.3

Comment: Can you please post the output you get when running task pull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in version 1.9.4 (see [Ticket #673](http://taskwarrior.org/issues/673) and [Ticket #548](http://taskwarrior.org/issues/548)).